# Debian msgpack install error java maven

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, installation, msgpack

**Background** : 
Linux ROCKMAN 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.6.0_32
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.2.0-4-amd64" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
java version "1.6.0_32"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
javac 1.6.0_32

**What I have tried**
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java/wiki/QuickStart

**1. $ git clone git@github.com:msgpack/msgpack-java.git**
sarit@ROCKMAN:~/workspace/msgpack-java$ ls
LICENCE.sbt-extras.txt  msgpack-core    NOTICE   project    sbt
LICENSE.txt             msgpack.org.md  pom.xml  README.md  version.sbt

I got everything right the same repository except "pom.xml".

**2. Add pom.xml on my own version which is copy from link above.**
(I put space in front of angle bracket to display)

< dependencies>

  < dependency>
    < groupId>org.msgpack< /groupId>
    < artifactId>msgpack< /artifactId>
    < version>0.7.0-p1< /version>
  < /dependency>

< /dependencies>
**3. mvn package**
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
Project ID: unknown
POM Location: /home/sarit/workspace/msgpack-java/pom.xml
Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project unknown at /home/sarit/workspace/msgpack-java/pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project unknown at /home/sarit/workspace/msgpack-java/pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:404)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
  at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
  at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project unknown at /home/sarit/workspace/msgpack-java/pom.xml
   at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1599)
  at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1571)
  at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:506)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)
 ... 12 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Nov 02 01:51:51 ICT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/118M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Questions**
1. Where I can find a correct pom.xml?
I had asked google and it returns a variety of them.
Since I don't know much about pom.xml
2. Where should I start?
My goal is using "msgpack-java version".

**Solution:**
Thank you everyone!
I grabbed the dependecies all around from here.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.msgpack/msgpack/0.6.8
They are : 
javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar
json-simple-1.1.1.jar
junit-4.8.2.jar
msgpack-0.6.8.jar
After that I add External JARs file to my eclipse.
It done after all.

Comment: I use want to use msgpack in my application. I heard from the author of this library that it is in a transition period from version 6 to 7. So I am now considering compiled version of it. Do you have alternative solutions?

Comment: Thank you. I found a ready-made solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msgpack-java is migrating from an older version v06 to a faster version v07, and its build process has changed a lot.

1. msgpack-java's pom.xml can be found in the central repository: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/msgpack/msgpack-core/, which is generated by sbt, so you cannot find the pom.xml in the source repository.
2. Your dependency artifactId should be msgpack-core, instead of msgpack.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I just found the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this is that the repository you have cloned `git@github.com:msgpack/msgpack-java.git` is a scala build which uses [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) instead of Maven. That's the reason for your problems.

Comment: Thank you I will try sbt. Hope it has short learning curve for beginner.